# How to display/edit records using the flow builder?

Tags: visual-workflow

I need to show a list of records that the users can edit and save. For example:

The flow should show a list of accounts, for example:

```
Name    Surname Title   Email
Marco   White   Mr.     marco@white.com
Lido    White   Mr.     lido@white.com
Esther  White   Mrs.    esther@white.com
```

Then, in the same flow, one can edit any field.

Are there any built-in features on flows to accomplish this?

I managed to get a list of records in the flow and store them in a variable, I used [this](http://Query%20records%20using%20collection%20variable%20in%20flow) article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's not possible for the moment if you can use only the standard components. there are 2 possible ways:

- Custom Lightning Component
- Packages from [AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/) (i'm not sure if there's a package for that, but you can give it a try)

You can upvote an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxGFAAY) that asks the same thing that you questioned.

I'm sorry for my english, i hope you understand what i said :D

Comment: Thanks a lot @Christian Croce!!